# Cookies secure flag in IE and Chrome browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, browser

We have recently configured our Asp.net Web application to support SSL using below code. When we test using Chrome's developer tools, could see Cookies set with Secure flag but in IE 11, secure flags are not set. Which one is correct and How to test properly?

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

Comment: I’d start by checking in dev tools what the actual Set-Cookie header looks like ...

Comment: @CBroe - It would be helpful, if u let me know where I can check Set-Cookie header in IE11 and Chrome

Comment: Well network panel in dev tools ...

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer:

- Click F12 for developer tools.
- Navigate to Network tab.
- Click "start capturing" and navigate to your website.
- Double click on the correct URL to get Detailed View.
- Navigate to the cookies tab in detail view to determine how the cookie was received from web server.
- Check to ensure the cookie direction is Received.